# How do I execute a stored procedure whenever an item is added to a service broker queue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, service-broker

I am using SQL Service Broker. I have a queue that another process is adding items to. I want to run a stored procedure whenever items are added to the queue. The procedure will receive the top item from the queue and use its information within the stored procedure. What is the correct syntax for doing something like this? Do I use a typical SQL Trigger or is there something special to use when working with Service Broker queues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A triggered stored procedure can be specified as part of the queue definition.
See the documentation for `CREATE QUEUE` - specifically the `ACTIVATION` clause.

An example from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190495.aspx):

> The following example creates a queue that is available to receive
>   messages. The queue starts the stored procedure expense_procedure when
>   a message enters the queue. The stored procedure executes as the user
>   ExpenseUser. The queue starts a maximum of 5 instances of the stored
>   procedure.
>
> ```
> CREATE QUEUE ExpenseQueue
>     WITH STATUS=ON,
>     ACTIVATION (
>         PROCEDURE_NAME = expense_procedure,
>         MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 5,
>         EXECUTE AS 'ExpenseUser' ) ;
> ```